# Using robot_pose_ekf in gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Now, I'm trying to use /robot_pose_ekf to publish the transform from odom -> base_footprint in gazebo simulation.

The tf tree tells me that the broadcaster of odom -> base_footprint is /gazebo, but I want it to be /robot_pose_ekf.

So I think the point to this question is how to prevent gazebo publishing the transform of odom -> base_footprint and let /robot_pose_ekf send the transform to /tf.

Actually, the tf tree shows both /gazebo and /robot_pose_ekf are connected to /tf, while /tf are using the transform of gazebo instead of /robot_pose_ekf, too bad :(

Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Clack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229312/using-robot_pose_ekf-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've fixed this problem, please refer to [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/229722/how-to-stop-gazebo-publishing-tf/).

Thank you for your attention ;)

---

Originally posted by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) with karma: 75 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0